# How to connect AWS Elastic Beanstalk spring boot java application to VisualVM [Not for tomcat]

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visualvm

I want to analyze spring boot application using VisualVM on elastic beanstalk application not for tomcat.